# GeoServer Timestamp/Timezone error convert

Tags: geoserver, wfs, datetime, timestamp

**Date format in PostgreSQL, -> 2019-10-30 08:46:44**

Created WFS, but got a problem.

GeoServer is converting the date. I think it somehow something with timezones.

**Output WFS -> 2019-10-30T07:46:44Z**

So one hour difference. Need timezone Amsterdam, not the standard.

How to solve this?

Comment: Looks like Zulu time, aka GMT, aka UTC.

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer (and GeoTools the underlying library) assume that all times and dates are stored in UTC - otherwise life just gets too complicated. You can either handle timezone conversion in the client or [set the `LOCAL_DATE_TIME_HANDLING` to true](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/metadata/geotools.html) and hope that everything works out (GeoServer doesn't really understand DST either).

Comment: Where can i do that?

Comment: where ever you handle server startup - on tomcat setenv.bat/sh, jetty - jetty,ini

Answer (score 0):

add this in the java options of start.ini file by vim editor present at /usr/share/geoserver/start.ini

```
-Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
-Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true
```

change time zone as per your region